# Complex Numbers -- Find $z$ such that $(z+1)^6 = z^6.$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Find all $z$ such that
$$(z+1)^6 = z^6.$$

I have moved $z + 1$ to the other side such that $$\left(\frac{z}{z+1}\right)^6 = 1,$$ which then makes it so

$$\frac{z}{z+1} = 1 = \frac{z}{z+1} = e^{ik\pi/3}.$$

I know $k \neq 0$ where $k = 0, 1, 2,\dotsc ,5$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Why not go with $$\left(\frac {z+1}{z}\right)^6 = \left(1 + \frac 1z\right)^6 = 1$$  when $z\neq 0$.

Comment: @AshleyXu: The equation $\frac z{z+1}=e^{ik\pi/3}$ is a first order equation ...

Comment: Hint (other than using the $6^{th}$ roots of unity):

$$
\begin{align}
(z+1)^6-z^6 &= \big((z+1)^3-z^3\big)\,\big((z+1)^3+z^3\big) \\
 &= \big((z+1)-z\big)\big((z+1)^2+(z+1)z+z^2\big)\,\big((z+1)+z\big)\big((z+1)^2-(z+1)z+z^2\big)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I tried editing your question, please check if it is what you meant.

Comment: I don't know the best way to do this, but what about geometrically using the angle info you've been looking at so far: first finding all $z$ such that $(z+1)^2=z^2$, i.e. the two numbers should be diametric opposites and differ by 1. Then those where $(z+1)^3=z^3$, then those where the former two equations are not true but the given one is?  For example, it seems to me that the four complex 6th roots of 1 differ by 1 in pairs set angle $\pi/3$ apart.  In the cube case you're basically looking for isosceles triangles with largest angle $2\pi/3$ and largest side length 1.

Comment: At any rate, definitely split it up into cases where $z/(z+1)$ has argument $\pi$, argument $\pm 2\pi/3$, and argument $\pm \pi/3$.  That's what I was trying to get across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already found that $$\frac{z}{z+1}=e^{ik\frac{\pi}{3}}$$

This can be rearranged to get $$z=\frac{e^{ik\frac{\pi}{3}}}{1-e^{ik\frac{\pi}{3}}}$$

You can simplify this using trig form and double angle identites to get your solution as $$z=-\frac 12+i\cot \left(k\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$